# Shift Keys Stays Pressed in Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Classic

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, pocketpc, windows-embedded

I'm writing a program for a handheld barcode scanner which uses Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Classic.

I have added a LinkLabel on my form and have coded it so that when you press Shift and click the link it brings up an input box for you to enter a password (I'll be replacing this with an actual form eventually but it is an InputBox for the time being)

When I let go of shift and begin to type my password using the physical keys (it is currently a 4 digit number) it treats the first character as though I am still holding shift.

Is there any way, in code, to revert it back so that shift isn't pressed?
I have tried to use the keybd_event api and it doesn't seem to work

This is what I've tried but I can't seem to find anything else to try.

```
Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "coredll.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Private Sub lblTitle_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblTitle.Click
    Try
        If GetKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Dim StaffPassword as String = "1234"
        Dim _Continue As Boolean = False

        keybd_event(VK_Shift, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0)
        keybd_event(VK_Shift, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)

        Do Until _Continue
            Dim _Password As String = InputBox("Please enter the staff password to go into the Admin Screen.", "Enter Password", "", True)

            If Not _Password = StaffPassword Then
                Dim _Ans As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("You entered an incorrect password!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Would you like to try again?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Incorrect Password")

                If _Ans = MsgBoxResult.No Then Exit Sub
            Else
                _Continue = True
            End If
        Loop

        frmAdmin.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please could someone help?

Comment: Try combining the two statements into one: `keybd_event(VK_Shift, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.  The device seems to keep it in its memory whether the shift key was pressed, even though you're not still pressing it.  It makes it easier when typing text messages and such, so that you press shift (rather than press and hold) and then it will capitalise the next character.

Comment: In your code it will be easier to use ToUpper() or try with VK_CAPITAL (0x14) instead of VK_SHIFT (0x10)

Comment: Sorry, I think you may have misunderstood.  I want to press and hold the shift key when clicking on a control so that an input box comes up and asks for a password. When the password box appears, its as though the shift key is still pressed. I want it to not be pressed at that point. I was only describing what it currently does when speaking about capitalising the first character with text messages.

Comment: Have you considered taking a different approach?  This does not seem user friendly in any way, and many devices don't even have an easily accessible hardware shift key.  Think of your poor users and find a different way to launch your login dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to revert the shift effect but maybe a simple workaround could do it. I'm only suggesting this approach because windows ce devices often have non-standard (hardware) keyboards whose drivers are not always perfect.

Since you are only expecting numbers you could try to detect a non-number char and map it to the corresponding number on the keyboard.